# how to let Azure facet query just return facet

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have this basic facet query `&facet=IncAcc` and I just want to return a count of different facet values.

Azure search returned not only facet values and Count, but also an array of search documents. As I just need facet value and count, is there a way to tell azure search not to return anything else?

```
"@search.facets": {
        "IncAcc": [
            {
                "count": 8124,
                "value": "I"
            },
            {
                "count": 6464,
                "value": "A"
            },
            {
                "count": 5,
                "value": ""
            }
        ]
    },"value": [
    {
    }
```

Comment: I answered a similar question a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512956/get-all-facets-from-azure-search-without-item-result. See if this helps.

Comment: stupid me, just need to add $top=0